# Swift 4 run code in background triggered by pomodoro timer

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to create a pomodoro app which I'm trying to run in the background.  My issue is that I would like the app to persist once it goes into the background and to signal the end of work sessions with a notification.

I've seen other posts relating to this general problem of running timers in the background but none of the proposed solutions work for my purpose.  I can't just compare the backgrounding time with the foregrounding time as I need to be doing things in the intervening time when the app is in the background (sending notifications and setting new timers for the next work session).

The other solution I've seen is to schedule local notifications at the times I need.  This wouldn't work as my pomodoro app might be backgrounded for a long time during which some arbitrary number of notifications might need to be triggered.  I have no way of predicting how many notifications I might need preschedule and I would prefer something more elegant than setting all of them and hoping for the best.

Ideally, my app would set a timer, go into the background, come back when the timer expired, determine how long of a timer it should set next, set it, and then go dormant.  Is there any way I can implement this?

Comment: Pomodoro timers work in 20 minute increments usually, right? Is there a reason you couldn't schedule all the timers that take place in the next 24 hours at once?

Comment: Basically, I could do that (it's the solution I'm keeping in my back pocket).  However, I would prefer a more elegant solution than that one.  In addition, pomodoro timers don't fire at regular intervals, since the work and break intervals are of different length, so it would be messy as well to schedule all the timers at once.